# javascript for office addin load at startup

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office365

I want to write a Powerpoint 2013+ addin using the Javascript API for Office. I have found multiple samples, but i don't see how to specify that my addin gets loaded/made available every time Powerpoint starts. I want to add my menu item so while a presentation is loaded a click of my menu item will allow me to send the current presentation up to a cloud service for further processing.

I imagine my addin would get installed via the office store.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123515.aspx

It explains all the publishing options currently available. Automagically loading is AFAICT currently not (yet) available.